# "У меня все в порядке" or "со мной все в порядке"

Tags: грамматика, предлоги

Which preposition is correct to use with 'все в порядке'?

Comment: Please uppercase titles in your questions whenever it makes sense (and it makes almost always)

Answer (score 8):

Both prepositions are correct, depending on meaning.

"у меня все в порядке" means "I'm doing fine", "Things are all right"

"со мной все в порядке" means "I'm good" (not hurt, not gone crazy)

Comment: Just trying to provide an understandable explanation to an English-speaking person: `у меня` is tricky, but in fact associates with the belongings and matters, "my business is doing well". The `со мной` has a close connotation of "own body", so, "me, personally and physically" (and, by extension, mentally, or similar things, but it's about personal well-being in this case. So, basically, "my business crashed (and I am filling for bankruptcy" vs. "my car crashed, but I'm fine".